# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "productname": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to make a database in my app. Unfortunately I am running in some trouble running my app.

DbHandler class:

```
package com.example.jarno.a49_savingdata;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by jarno on 24-1-17.
 */

public class MyDbHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "products.db";
    public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";

    public MyDbHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
                COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT "  +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS" + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addProduct(Products product) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public void delProduct(String productName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "=\"" + productName + "\";" );
    }

    public String databaseToString() {
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";

        // Cursor point to a location in the results
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        // Move to the first row in the results
        c.moveToFirst();

        while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null) {
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
        }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.jarno.a49_savingdata, PID: 4115
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jarno.a49_savingdata/com.example.jarno.a49_savingdata.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "productname": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE products(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT productname TEXT ):
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "productname": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE products(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT productname TEXT ):
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
                                                     at com.example.jarno.a49_savingdata.MyDbHandler.onCreate(MyDbHandler.java:31)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                     at com.example.jarno.a49_savingdata.MyDbHandler.databaseToString(MyDbHandler.java:55)
                                                     at com.example.jarno.a49_savingdata.MainActivity.printDatabase(MainActivity.java:40)
                                                     at com.example.jarno.a49_savingdata.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I think there must be something wrong with this code, but I can't find out what:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
                COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT "  +
                ");";
```

Comment: And where is the **comma**, to separate your field definitions?!

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know, sorry.

Comment: here is the trick... look at this part of the erro `CREATE TABLE products(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT productname TEXT )` and find the problem

Comment: Yeah I knew that, but I didn't know there had to be a comma. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a comma after `AUTOINCREMENT` as you're declaring a new column

```
COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
```